# How to bind the function by use @inject?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

When I use the `mobx-react` ,I use inject decorator to transmit the store.But when I get the store such as

```
@inject("store") @observer
class item extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.store = this.props.store;
  }
}
```

But when I want to call the function of `store` such as `store.getUser()` , I found that the context `getUser` function is not `this` , how can I bind `this` to the `store` ?

PS: the store is such as following :

```
class Store {
  @observable user = "Sarah";
  @computed
  get getUser() {
    return user + "Ok";
  }
}
export default new Store();
```

I use the `getUser` like

```
render() {
  <div>{this.store.getUser()}</div>
}
```

Comment: can you add the code where you call `getUser`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `this.user` in your store:

```
class Store {
  @observable user = "Sarah";
  @computed
  get getUser() {
    return this.user + "Ok";
  }
}
export default new Store();
```

A `computed` is a getter, so you don't access it with a function call. Just dereference the field:

```
render() {
  <div>{this.store.getUser}</div>
}
```

Comment: oh, sorry, that's my lapsus calami，I used `this.user` in my code.

Comment: @YingchXue I see. Could you add the rest of the `Component` in your code?

Comment: @YingchXue No problem. Does it work? Consider accepting the answer.

Comment: sorry, my reputation score is not enough,so I cannot accept.I will accept this after I have 15. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Store {
  @observable user = "Sarah";
  @computed
  get okUser() {
    return this.user + "Ok";
  }
}

const store = new Store();
console.log(store.okUser);
```

`@computed` is getter so you do not need to call it as function.